# Is the gcd of two numbers also the gcd of their squares?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm working on a problem and I would like to use this fact, but I don't have anything to write on so I am having trouble figuring it out.

Is it always true that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a^n, b^n)$?

I know it has to be true for prime numbers. I'm not sure about composite ones.

Comment: $gcd(a^n,b^n)=(gcd(a,b))^n$

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know!

Comment: Obviously not. If $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, $d^n$ divides both $a^n$ and $b^n$, hence $\gcd(a^n,b^n)\geq\gcd(a,b)^n$. You just need to show that $\leq $ holds, too.

Comment: probably confusing with the fact that, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $a^n$ and $b^n$ are also coprime.

Comment: Yep, @Bernard, that's what happened.

Comment: Note there's no contradiction: if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, their g.c.d. is equal to $1$, and $1^n=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: When trying to figure out things like this, it's very helpful to try some simple examples,  like for example $ a = b = 2$.

Answer (score 4):

Only if they're coprime to begin with, that is, $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. If the the two numbers share a common prime factor, $p$, then $a^2$ is divisible by $p^2$ and so is $b^2$.

An example to make it clearer: $\gcd(4, 14) = 2$ and $\gcd(16, 196) = 4$.